# Como trago um select de valores definidos em um Controller no angular.js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Desculpem mas sou leigo e estou começando!
No HTML, eu quero apresentar os dados definidos numa classe controller do angular. Conforme abaixo:

```
$scope.tiposCategorias = [
                            { id: 1, descricao:'Processados'},
                            { id: 2, descricao:'Naturais'}, 
                            { id: 3, descricao:'Perecíveis'}, 
                            { id: 4, descricao:'Antiperecíveis'}
                    ];
```

Na view faço um crud básico, mas selecionando apenas os dados que já estão definidos na classe controller. Conforme abaixo:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="categoria.tipoCategoria" ng-options="tp.id as tp.descricao for tp in tiposCategorias" required></select>
```

Após isso, quero apresentá-los em uma tabela do HTML. Conforme o código abaixo:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cate in listaCategorias | filter:criteria">
    <td>
        {{cate.tipoCategoria==1?'Processados':'Naturais':'Perecíveis':'Antiperecíveis'}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Porém, quando escolho a opção e salvo, nenhuma informação aparece. A tabela fica nula. Sei que o erro é quando chamo o parâmetro do angular para mostrar a informação dentro da tabela, mas não sei como corrigir isso.

Obrigado desde já se alguém conseguir entender onde está o erro.

Comment: @Lucas Duete, você poderia disponibilizar o restante do código? ficaria mais simples para entender aonde está o problema. Por exemplo, o que é realizado com as informações do objeto categoria?

Comment: Por favor forneca mais trechos do seu código para facilita encontrar o problema

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Olá acredito que entendi oque precisa. Acho que é bem tranquilo pra fazer.
Pra ficar legal você só precisa usar a função filter para buscar o item que quer cadastrar do array inicial.
Vou colocar o código abaixo.

```js
app = angular.module('meuapp', []);

    app.controller('moduloArray', function($scope) {
        $scope.tiposCategorias = [{
            id: 1,
            descricao: 'Processados'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            descricao: 'Naturais'
        }, {
            id: 3,
            descricao: 'Perecíveis'
        }, {
            id: 4,
            descricao: 'Antiperecíveis'
        }];

        $scope.listaCategorias = Array();
        $scope.adicionarItem = function(categoria) {
          $scope.categoria.tipoCategoria = null;
          //filtrando apenas o item que quer cadastrar para pegar a descrição
          var a = $scope.tiposCategorias.filter((item) => (item.id == categoria))[0].descricao;
          $scope.listaCategorias.push({
              id: categoria,
              descricao: a
          });
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="meuapp">
    <div ng-controller="moduloArray">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="categoria.tipoCategoria" ng-options="tp.id as tp.descricao for tp in tiposCategorias" required></select>
        <button ng-disabled="!categoria.tipoCategoria" ng-click="adicionarItem(categoria.tipoCategoria)">+</button>
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="cate in listaCategorias track by $index">
                <td>
                    {{$index+') '+'ID: '+cate.id+' Tipo: '+cate.descricao}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado um pouco.

Comment: Ajudou muito, era essa dúvida que eu tinha na hora de selecionar o valor e salvá-lo. Obrigado pela ajuda Cleyton!